# "Reading" a POD preincrement result does not yield undefined behavior. Why exactly?

Tags: c++, c, standards, language-lawyer

**This is a stupid question.**  :)

**[EDIT: stupid or not, this turned out to be a C++ peculiarity question, see UPDATE_2]**

Suppose we have:

```
int a = 0; // line 1
int b = ++a; // line 2
```

What happens in line 2 is (*note, numbers are just markers and do not specify exact order*):

```
                      = [1: write result of (3) to result of (2)]
                     /\
[2: take "b" l-value] [3: convert result of (4) to an r-value ]
                      |
                      [4: take "a" l-value, "increment" and return it]
```

The "write" in (4) is "ordered" before the "read" in (3), and since there are no sequence points between, the side-effect is not guaranteed to happen before (3) (there is also a "read" inside (4) itself, but ordered *before* "write", so that does not yield UB).

So, where is the error in the above?

**[UPDATE, aimed at not seasoned sequence-point lawyers :)]**

In other words the problem is:

1. There seems to be  a "competition" whether the l-value-to-r-value conversion ("read") or increment ("write") side-effect takes place first.
2. In C, that *would give an UB*, according to [JTC1/SC22/WG14 N926 "Sequence Point Analysis"](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/n926.htm)* (see, for example, EXAMPLE 5: `int x,y; (x=y) + x; // UB`).
3. *Note this would not be a case should postincrement be used since (3) and (4) will constitute a single* [(3): take "a" l-value, convert it to r-value and return that r-value] *with the "write" side-effect delayed until somewhere before the next sequence point*

_

(*) This looks like the cleanest systematic rationale for the topic given by the C99 Standards Committee members.

**[UPDATE_2]**

1. Lesson learned: never judge C++ by C rules :)). I did exactly that wondering why the N926 (which cleanly describes the C99 way of things) was "not clear enough" on the topic of preincrements yielding l-values.
2. The question arises, how would one build a similar rationale for C++, as there isn't one, since even in the C case just interpreting the standard is pretty hard, and the C++ language standard is much more complicated and obscure.

**[UPDATE_3]**

**There's a discussion dealing with some relevant topics (at least in the ~newer half) at ["The undefinedness of a common expression."](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c/browse_thread/thread/bdae87d399a9442e/c8b377fc39551c66?hl=en&), plus the matter is discussed by the committee people [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2029.html)(see "222. Sequence points and lvalue-returning operators").**

Comment: Hmm, interesting. The problem only occurs in C++ though, not in C (++a in C is not an lvalue).

Comment: Thanks for the update, which makes the question more obviously interesting.  Apparently I was also not seasoned enough to guess from your `C` tag that you were only after C++ considerations.

Comment: @John That was _my_ fault (and also the _inconsistency_ leading to the question itself, see update_2).

Comment: btw i really like your linked paper. I'm just reading into it and it's quite interesting :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution may be in the wording of "++i". It says "The value is the new value of the operand; it is an lvalue.". And behavior is undefined in 5/4 by "Furthermore, the prior value shall be accessed only to determine the value to be stored.".

So, we are not accessing the prior, but the new value. And then we may be fine. It seems to be a very thin line between undefined behavior and defined behavior though.

Actually "prior value" sounds to me like "value the object had at the previous sequence point". And if interpreted like that, then this construct looks undefined. But if we directly compare the wording of "++i" in 5.3/2 to 5/4, we are confronted by "new value" vs "prior value", and things are "bent" to defined behavior ("++i" would peek at the value of "i" at the next sequence point, and produce that value as the contents of the resulting lvalue of "++i").

Comment: So, do you see a way to extend N926 analysis method to support the C++ case in question?

Comment: Added a comp.lang.c discussion link, if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

The main sentence in C++ 5/4 is

> Between the previous and next sequence point a scalar object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.

(And the sentence quoted by Johannes is the following, subordinate one.)

Which scalar object do you suspect is having its stored value modified more than once here?  `a` and `b` are modified once each on line 2, so there is no problem.

(Similar language is in 6.5/2 in the C standard.)

---

EDIT:

> The "write" in (4) is "ordered" before the "read" in (3), and since there are no sequence points between, the side-effect is not guaranteed to happen before (3)

On re-reading your question, I think the confusion comes from a confused way of thinking about `++a`: the expression doesn't really peek at the future value of `a`.  Rather, it might help to think of `++a` as "return `a+1` and as a side-effect increment `a`, at your leisure (before the next sequence point)".

So who cares whether that side-effect happens before or after (3)?  The value of the expression, which is what is fed to (3), is already determined.

Comment: @John, the point is that when you do `++a` in C++, it does *not* automatically yield `a+1` as a value independent of changing its stored value, because then it can't be an lvalue. In C++ you can do such things as `int *p = &++i;` which are not allowed in C. What happens in C++ for stuff like `++a + 1` is that you modify the stored value of `a` and also read its value inbetween the same sequence points *not* to determine the value to be stored but to further process it.

Comment: @litb: exactly, I'm updating my post with what actually was a comment outpaced by yours:))

Comment: Chapter and verse?  Because I keep reading 5/4 and 5.3.2/2 ("The value is the new value of the operand; it is an lvalue") and I just don't see that that implies that the scalar object is re-read (in an as-if world).

Comment: well the wording is unfortunate (since it uses "value", which in C terms means "non-lvalue", but in C++ doesn't imply that). It is fixed in C++0x to say "The result is the updated operand.". But as it is an lvalue, there is no doubt about a second read. See 4.1 for the actions taken to convert an lvalue to an rvalue, which includes accessing the value stored therein. And 5/8 which is responsible for triggerig that conversion if an operand is an lvalue but an rvalue is expected.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: If `r` is an extern volatile which maps to a hardware register, and `i` is a local variable, would `i=++r;` be required then to read `r`, store that value plus one into `r`, read `r` again, and store that value into `i`?  Would the second read only happen if something used the value yielded by `++r`?